# How to remove interesting tags

Tags: support, tags

One of my interesting tags is not bringing up data.  Seems the community has deemed it necessary to add dashes to it.  How do I get rid of this tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of any interesting tag by hovering over the X mark which will then allow you to click and delete that tag from your list.

Note: This has to be done from your interesting tag list. You can't just hover over any old tag displayed anywhere.

Comment: I think the problem was that they have 'Tagname' x 132 - as you can see on the right of this page.  I thought the x was just some bad formatting on their part.

Comment: Yeah it can be a little confusing at first.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the home page, there should be an 'x' by the tag which will remove it. The same is true under Users - tab Preferences.

Comment: This is the answer that got it for me, the 'correct' answer doesn't explain where the 'interesting tag list' is... you have to go to the root/Home page. There's no button to get there that I can see, you just have to click the 'StackOverflow' logo